# Entity Framework return all projects that contain substring

Tags: c#, entity-framework, asp.net-core

I'm working in a asp.net core site where i'm trying to query our project database through the entity framework. Our Project ID's are set up as so:

0192-10-001, 
0192-10-001A, 
0192-10-001B,
0192-10-001C,
0192-10-001BE,
...

for the same project but tracked by letters through separate departments. I want to be able to strip out the letters and return all projects that are affiliated by substring (0192-10-001).I'm newer to linq and I'm most likely overthinking this entirely but I'm hoping someone can point me in the right direction.

I've tried the following queries:

```
//This is what I thought would work
return _context.Projects.Where(a => a.Project_ID.Contains(ID));

//Another approach
return _context.Projects.Where(a => a.Project_ID == ID);

//Getting more confused and desperate
return _context.Projects.Where(a => ID.Any(n => a.Project_ID.Contains(ID)));
```

Let me know if you need any more information!

Comment: what are you currently getting as a result and what you expect instead?

Comment: WHat do you mean `strip out the letters`?Could you give a sample result which you would like to get?If you want to retrieve all records contains the ID,`_context.Projects.Where(p => p.Project_ID.Contains(ID)).ToList();` works well.

Comment: Thank you all for answering and all these answers were correct! It ended up being a mistyped URL and it wasn't collecting the string correctly. Which makes sense when nothing was returning!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you would like to return List of Projects whose Project_IDs contain `ID`("0192-10-001"),just use

```
var list = _context.Projects.Where(p => p.Project_ID.Contains(ID)).ToList();
```

Answer (score 0):

It's work for me. But search text must match with ID.

```
var filtered = _context.Projects.Where(x => "0192-10-001".Contains(x.ID)).ToList();
```

You can put variable instead of "0192-10-001" text.